# Notation on a put spread?

Tags: options

I'm reading a document that states the following:

> 1 year, European, 1250/1000 put spread

Does this mean it's a bull or bear put spread?

Comment: Ah, I was not aware.  Although this is for a quantitative problem, this specific part (the one I'm asking about) is more money related.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you're buying 1250 and selling 1000 -> short delta -> bear PS